# Type 'DBTweet' does not conform to protocol 'Decodable'

Tags: swift, decodable

I want my strcut to conform to decodable, but I always get this error although i conformed to it.

> Type 'DBTweet' does not conform to protocol 'Decodable'

That's my code:

```
struct DBTweet {
    private(set) public var user: DBUser
    private(set) public var profileImage: UIImage?
    private(set) public var tweetID: Int
    private(set) public var content: String
    private(set) public var postedImageURL: String?
    private(set) public var timestamp: String
    private(set) public var comments: [DBComment]
}

extension DBTweet: Decodable {
    enum MyStructKeys: String, CodingKey { // declaring our keys
        case user, tweetID, content, postedImageURL, timestamp, comments
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't implemented the the init(from: Decoder).
You can conform your models to Codable(Decodable) also without implement them if all of your model property conform to Codable to.

```
struct DBTweet: Codable {
    private(set) public var user: DBUser
    private(set) public var profileImage: UIImage?
    private(set) public var tweetID: Int
    private(set) public var content: String
    private(set) public var postedImageURL: String?
    private(set) public var timestamp: String
    private(set) public var comments: [DBComment]
}
```

Be sure that also DBUser, and DBComment conforms to Codable

[UPDATE]
With init:

```
struct DBTweet: Decodable {
    private(set) public var user: DBUser
    private(set) public var profileImage: UIImage?
    private(set) public var tweetID: Int
    private(set) public var content: String
    private(set) public var postedImageURL: String?
    private(set) public var timestamp: String
    private(set) public var comments: [DBComment]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case user, tweetID, content, postedImageURL, timestamp, comments
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        self.user = try container.decode(DBUser.self, forKey: .user)
        self.profileImage = nil // Construct here your profileImage
        self.tweetID = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .tweetID)
        self.content = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .content)
        self.postedImageURL = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .postedImageURL)
        self.timestamp = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .timestamp)
        self.comments = try container.decode([DBComment].self, forKey: .comments)
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes without init and the profileImage property it works ,but I have added the profileImage that I don't want to be decoded because I want to add it manually in my code so I have to add init decoder or not?

Comment: Updated the answer, please upvote it if it was helpful

Comment: I get this error: Value of type 'Decoder' has no member 'container'

Comment: Unfortunately still the same error. Its very weird. It happens in the first line in the init block

Comment: oh, I know why. I have another struct called Decoder